# How to combine two data columns in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have two tables, like below. I want to merge two table into 1. I tried to merge,concat, join in panda but it gives a new table of height 20, I want to have a height of 10 in the new combined table. How to do this one panda data frames? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you need `df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```